# Laravel: creating resource route results in artisan error

Tags: laravel, routes, resources, laravel-artisan

I put this in my routes:

```
Route::resource('post', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'PostController']);
```

and I am getting this error in php artisan:

```
[ErrorException]            
  Array to string conversion
```

What's going on here?

edit-- it seems to be bound to the use of the middleware.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Second parameter must be a [controller class name only](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers). If you want to add middleware, [use groups](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-groups):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::resource('post', 'PostController']);
});
```